# tooltip on disabled button does not work on internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using a solution like this one http://jsfiddle.net/cSSUA/209/ for applying a tooltip on disabled buttons, but it doesn't work on Internet Explorer (IE11 in my case).

Essentially the workaround is based on a wrapping div:

```
<span class="tooltip-wrapper" title="Nessun esito selezionato">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" disabled><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Rifiuta</button>
</span>
```

, in CSS:

```
.tooltip-wrapper {
  display: inline-block; /* display: block works as well */
}

.tooltip-wrapper .btn[disabled] {
  /* don't let button block mouse events from reaching wrapper */
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

and in jQuery:

```
$('.tooltip-wrapper').tooltip({position: "bottom"});
```

I see in DOM explorer that the tooltip is created but I don't understand why I can't see the tooltip.

I'm so sorry for my bad english and for my bad knowledge of HTML/CSS/javascript/jQuery/Bootstrap.

Comment: Your fiddle works fine in version 80 MS Edge.

Comment: Seems to work in Firefox and Chrome, too.

Comment: Why would you disable pointer events for a disabled button? I think the `click` event never fires in disabled buttons.

Comment: @D.Pardal you are right, I've disabled pointer events because if someone reads the code, the fact that the button cannot be interacted is much more evident.

Comment: @dalelandry & others I thank you to confirm that the fiddle works on those browsers :) my concern is about Internet Explorer 11 because I have a specific request about it and I don't understand what is happenening in that scenario, becuase there is a strange beahaviour.

Comment: Neither stackoverflow or jsfiddle support IE11 any longer. IE11 will continue to be supported by Microsoft until 2025. 

What is your html code?

Comment: @dalelandry I've edited my post and I've added the html code. Unfortunately the request to support internet explorer 11 is due to an explicit customer request.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); 
});
```

```css
.tooltip-wrapper {
  display: inline-block; /* display: block works as well */
  margin: 50px; /* make some space so the tooltip is visible */
  z-index: 2;
}

.tooltip-wrapper .btn[disabled] {
  /* don't let button block mouse events from reaching wrapper */
  pointer-events: none;
}

.tooltip-wrapper.disabled {
  /* OPTIONAL pointer-events setting above blocks cursor setting, so set it here */
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-663tSdtipgBgyqJXfypOwf9ocmvECGG8Zdl3q+tk+n0="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
Add a `title` attribute for your display text, and use the `$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]` attribute to call on your function. Tested in IE11 using JQuery 1.10.1 and it works.
  
<div class="tooltip-wrapper disabled" data-title="tooltip" title="Dieser Link führt zu Google">
  <button class="btn btn-default" disabled>button disabled</button>
</div>
```